# ArcGIS Javascript - Angular - Memory not getting freed

Tags: javascript, angular, memory, arcgis, esri

Good Day

I'm using Angular 9.3 and I've noticed that when I load an ArcGIS map, and navigate away, no matter how I try to free / destroy it, it never works.

I've created a sample repo: https://github.com/docmur/angular-esri-memory-test

When I navigate to the GIS map, with the button, wait for the map to load and move back to the dashboard, the memory isn't getting freed.  I've noticed this to a much greater extent on my main application, which is where I noticed this memory leak.

If I move from the map to the dashboard (which says Empty Page), then check the Dev Console -> Memory Tab, I see:

[image: Memory Tab Dev Console]

If I take a snapshot and look a the memory, I see:

[image: Heap Snapshot]

I've asked this over at the ESRI Forums:  https://community.esri.com/thread/257479-how-do-you-clean-up-the-memory-angular-9-javascript

To no response.  I'm I doing something wrong or is this a bug with Angular, ESRI or Angular and ESRI?

Thanks